# How can I print control characters in a readable format?

Tags: c++, string, formatting, escaping

I have a program which tends to output control characters from time to time, and I'd like them to be printed in caret notation and colored in blue (like `vim`). Right now, I use a function that calls `boost::algorithm::replace_all()` for each of the control characters I could think of (`^A` through `^Z`, plus `^@` and a few others), on a string before printing it.

Is there a better way to do this? My current solution seems workaroundish and prone to errors.

Comment: Does your program only output characters in the ASCII range (`\x00` to `\x7F`)? If not -- how do you want to handle characters outside that range?

Comment: For the most part, yes, but there is the occasional ellipses character, and other things. Characters outside of the ASCII range should probably be left alone in this case—The current setup handles those characters well.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution (probably not the most elegant):

```
std::string escape_control_characters(const std::string & s)
{
    std::string ret;
    for(std::string::const_iterator iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end(); ++iter)
    {
        const char c = *iter;
        if(c < ' ')
        {
            ret.push_back('^');
            ret.push_back(c + '@');
        }
        else if(c == '\x7F')
            ret.append("^?");
        else
            ret.push_back(c);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

[[demo](http://ideone.com/Mj7EmP)]

This doesn't handle colored-in-blue part, but it sounds like you already know how to do that?

By the way, you may want to change `if(c < ' ')` to something like `if(c < ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n')`, since although tab and newline are technically control characters (`^I` and `^J`, respectively), it's probably O.K. to print them.